# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException(hbase)

Tags: hbase

i had my hbase + hadoop cluster,and when i used hbase api to access hbase,everthing is ok.but,when i use the jar command to package class files,something wrong happend.how can i do?
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getResource(Configuration.java:1862)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:2047)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResources(Configuration.java:2001)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getProps(Configuration.java:1918)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.get(Configuration.java:721)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTrimmed(Configuration.java:740)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getBoolean(Configuration.java:1093)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration.checkDefaultsVersion(HBaseConfiguration.java:69)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration.addHbaseResources(HBaseConfiguration.java:105)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration.create(HBaseConfiguration.java:120)
    at geoDatasDAO.(geoDatasDAO.java:49)
    at geoDatasTool.main(geoDatasTool.java:220)

Comment: Can you provide more details like which distribution and which version of Hbase you're using? What's your complete use-case?

Comment: my hadoop is 2.7.0,and hbase is 0.98.12.1.And when i use the jar command ro package class files,it's wrong.the error statement is conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();

Comment: what's happened? and how can i do?